# Buttons not responding to clicks - Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a simple app that updates a counter with plus/minus buttons. I have implemented onClickListeners but I can't get the counter to update based on clicks. I am running my app in an emulator, the application uploads and installs successfully. I also don't see the print statements in the logcat. Please help. Thank you.

```
package testapp.two;

import testapp.two.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button okButton, minusButton, plusButton;
    TextView textScore, scoreCard;
    int score = 95;
    private static final String TAG = "GolfScore";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate started"); 

    okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
    minusButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
    plusButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
    textScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textScore);
    scoreCard = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreCard);

    //set button listeners
    okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    minusButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    plusButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate finished");
    }//onCreate

@Override   
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "in onClick");

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonMinus:
            score--;
            textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonPlus:
            score++;
            textScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            break;

        case R.id.buttonOK:
            break;
        }//end of switch

    }//end of my onclick

}//end of MainActivity
```

activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:text="Golf Score App"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="91"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOK"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreCard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Score card info goes here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="testapp.two"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try clean and build the project first

Comment: are you able to see `91` or `95`in  `textScore` TextView?

Comment: Yes, I see 91 in textScore.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just declare a new View.OnClickListener() rather than having Main activity implement it... that just seems weird to me. Then set the click listener to that